# Проблема с массивом со значениями Any

Tags: массивы, swift, if, условия, any

Я новичок в Swift не судите строго мой код, как сделать чтоб условия if понимала Any массив и могло определять правильно, строковое от числового значения и не только.

```
var zz:[Any]=[1,7,9,"str","xi"]
for s in zz{
 if s==9{
   continue
 } 
 print("#\(s)")
}
```

Comment: "чтоб условия работало правильно" - что такое правильно, в вашем понимании?

Comment: чтоб if  понимал значения Any, не зависимо это будем, строковое или числовое значения.

Comment: Для этого вам нужно привести его к нужному вам типа: s as! String, s as! Int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно так

```
var zz:[Any]=[1,7, 9 ,"str","xi"]
for s in zz{

    guard let ss = s as? Int else {
        print("#\(s)") // выполняется если s не Int
        continue 
    }
    // выполняется если s Int
    if ss == 9{
        continue
    }

    print("#\(s)")
}
```

можно еще так

```
var zz:[Any]=[1,7, 9 ,"str","xi"]
for s in zz{

    if s is Int {
        // выполняется если s Int
        if s as! Int == 9{
            continue
        }
    }
    print("#\(s)")
}
```

или так

```
for s in zz{

    if !(s is Int) {
        // выполняется если s не Int
        print("#\(s)")
        continue
    }

    if s as! Int == 9{
        continue
    }

    print("#\(s)")
}
```

Comment: ок, а у нас в массиве и строковые данные есть,  а если мы их тоже тоже задействовать в цикл.

Comment: Ну через is можно проверять

Comment: Я  понял ) сам попытался ) но пишет  ошибку ) `var zz:[Any]=[1,7, 9 ,"str","xi"]
for s in zz{

    if s is Int {
        // выполняется если s Int
        if s as! Int == 9{
            continue
        } else{
         if s  as! String=="xi"{
           continue
         }
        }
    }
    print("#\(s)")
    }`

Comment: все разобрался спасибо ) за доброту )

Comment: нет вру не совсем разобрался не те данные вывел `var zz:[Any]=[1,7, 9 ,"str","xi"]
for s in zz{

    if s is Int {
        // выполняется если s Int
        if s as! Int == 9{
            continue
        }
      if s is String {
        // выполняется если s Int
        if s as! String == "xi"{
            continue
        }  
    }
    print("#\(s)")
}
}`

Comment: В этом коде пропускает весь массив кроме, последнего значения, хотел,  чтоб он только определенные данные пропускал не все. `var zz:[Any]=[1,7, 9 ,"str","xi"]
for s in zz{

    
      if s is String {
        // выполняется если s Int
        if s as! String == "str"{
            continue
        }  
      if s is Int {
        // выполняется если s Int
        if s as! Int == 7{
            continue
        }  
       
    }
    print("#\(s)")
}
}`

Comment: Какие пропускать ?

Comment: пропускал те значения, что мы обозначили в if, а все остальные выводил с ANY массива

Comment: у вас в  `if s is String` кавычка не закрыта (точнее не там закрыта). вот так выводит 1, 9, xi `var zz:[Any]=[1,7, 9 ,"str","xi"] 

    for s in zz{ 
        if s is String { 
             // выполняется если s String
             if s as! String == "str" { continue } 
        }
        if s is Int { 
             // выполняется если s Int 
             if s as! Int == 7 { continue } 
        } 
        print("#\(s)") 
     }`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71556/discussion-between-andrey-iskamov-and-life-).